# Is $X^\dagger \Sigma (I-XX^\dagger)$ equal to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Denote the Moore–Penrose inverse with $\dagger$. I would like to know if $X^\dagger \Sigma (I-XX^\dagger)$ equals zero, where $\Sigma$ is a full-rank diagonal matrix, and $X$ has full column rank for that matter.

Obviously, $X^\dagger \Sigma (I-XX^\dagger) = X^\dagger-X^\dagger XX^\dagger = 0$ when $\Sigma = I$, but what about otherwise? My guess is $X^\dagger \Sigma (I-XX^\dagger) \ne 0$ when $\Sigma \ne I$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: OK. How about $X = [1 \ 0; 0 \ 1; 0 \ 0]$?

Comment: Ha, interesting. In that case, the first two elements on the diagonal of $\Sigma$ can be any non-zero number, but $X^\dagger \Sigma (I-XX^\dagger)$ is still zero! Nice counter-example.